# I want to know when I have to use the word 'own'

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I just wonder when I have to use the word 'own'.

The word 'own' seems to be used like 'have'

What do you usually use between the below sentences?

1. I have my own house.
2. I own my house.

Answer (score 2):

> I have my own house.

Here, own is used as a determiner. You use own like this for emphasis, or to indicate that you also have something. For example:

> I used to share a flat with some friends but now I have my own [flat].
>   I didn't believe it until I saw it with my **own** eyes.

---

> I own my house.

When it is used as a verb, it indicates possession. By comparison, **have** an also mean that you have with you, or have in your possession, or have available for your use.

> I have a house - *it could be rented, and I just live in it*
>   I own a house - *it is my property*

See the [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/own) for more examples.